# after not working with canvas.itemconfig & text

Tags: python, canvas, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to change the text of a text object in a tkinter canvas. The normal `self.canvas.itemconfig(self.land[(0, 0)], text=str(self.ctr))` works, where self.land is a dictionary of ID's where the coordinate is the Key.
When I try to make the change wait a for a few seconds and use, `self.root.after(1000, self.canvas.itemconfig, self.land[(0, 0)], text=str(self.ctr))` I get "TypeError: after() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'" Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message said, `after` method does not accept text keyword argument.

Try following code:

```
self.root.after(1000, lambda: self.canvas.itemconfig(self.land[(0, 0)], text=str(self.ctr)))
```

Comment: Yup, thanks, that did the trick, I just wonder why after saw text as a variable for itself and not itemconfig.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, `after` does not pass keyword arguments to callback. See [after documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).